# Problems with reindexing products

Tags: mysql, indexing, php-5.4, magento-1.8

Magento tells me that I need to reindex, but Product Prices fails with either "There was a problem with reindexing process." or "Cannot initialize the indexer process".

I have tried removing everything in var/locks and var/report.
I have flushed and removed all cached files.
I also ran this SQL query:

```
DELETE pf1.*
FROM catalog_product_flat_1 pf1
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity p ON pf1.entity_id = p.entity_id
WHERE ISNULL( p.entity_id ) ;
```

This happened after I removed some entires from core_store_group and core_store because I couldn't remove some root categories from the interface before that. Everything related to these stores have been removed.

I have also tried running the indexer on the server with:

```
php shell/indexer.php --reindexall
```

It gave me:

```
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully
Product Prices index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cwd.date' in 'field list'' in /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php(134): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Downloadable_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#8 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Catalog/Product/Indexer/Price.php(193): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Catalog_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#10 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#11 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#12 /home/organico/public_html/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#13 /home/organico/public_html/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#14 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cwd.date' in 'field list'' in /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/organico/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php(134): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Resource/Indexer/Price.php(47): Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Downloadable_Indexer_Price->_prepareFinalPriceData()
#7 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Catalog/Product/Indexer/Price.php(193): Mage_Downloadable_Model_Resource_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#8 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Innoexts_AdvancedPricing_Model_Mysql4_Catalog_Product_Indexer_Price->reindexAll()
#9 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(210): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#10 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(258): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#11 /home/organico/public_html/shell/indexer.php(166): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#12 /home/organico/public_html/shell/indexer.php(212): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#13 {main}
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully
Category Products index was rebuilt successfully
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully
```

I run PHP version 5.4.19 and Magento 1.8.0.0
Sorry for the long question, cheers to anybody that actually takes the time to read the whole thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#6 /home/organico/public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php(134): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
```

The line above means:

Check your file /home/organico/public_html/app/code/local/Innoexts/AdvancedPricing/Model/Mysql4/Downloadable/Indexer/Price.php line 134.

It does an INSERT INTO and refers to a 'date' column that doesn't exist.

If you didn't make that extension, contact the person who made it.

If you want to make sure this is indeed the extension that is the problem, disable it and re-index your products, it should work.

Hope that helps.